# Decision Tree Sklearn- how to build a fully-grown tree with one data point at each terminal node?

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

How should I build a fully grown decision tree with one data point at each terminal node? I am looking for a tree model that gives an in-sample error rate equal to 0%.

```
from sklearn import tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0, min_samples_split=2, max_depth=100000000)
clf = clf.fit(feature, tgt)

pred = clf.predict(feature) * tgt 
len(pred[pred > 0]) / len(pred)
```

I am expecting a 1.0 from this code, but for some reason, get 57% instead.

Comment: does `tgt` contain any 0 values?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters nope. it is 1 and -1.

Comment: Leave `max_depth=None` and `min_samples_split=2` to expand nodes until all leaves are pure. Use `clf.score(feature, tgt)` to compute accuracy instead of the last two commands in your code.

Comment: @SanjarAdylov just tried. it worked. Can you add some explanations and put it in an answer?

Comment: @user1559897 Sure.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `max_depth=None` and `min_samples_split=2` so that a tree can expand until
all terminal nodes contain exactly one sample. That is, you don't have to guess the
maximum depth of a fully grown tree.

As for an error rate, you fail to get 1.0 because apparently,
you divide the number of *positive* samples `len(pred[pred > 0])` by the total number
of samples `len(pred)`. Try this:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.mean(clf.predict(feature) == tgt)
1.0
```

But it is more convenient to use `score` method provided by scikit-learn classifiers:

```py
>>> clf.fit(feature, tgt)
>>> clf.score(feature, tgt)
1.0
```

It returns the mean accuracy on the given features and targets, exactly what you are
looking for.

Comment: hmmmm the code posted does not "divide the number of positive samples len(pred[pred > 0]) by the total number of samples len(pred)".